# How to change the list box scroll bar view in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, scrollbar, customization

I'm developing windows phone 8 application. In this for list box and long list box, whenever there is more data, it will show a scroll bar.

**Now I want to change that default scroll bar view to like below.**

[image]

How should I? Please help me I'm new to Windows Phone development.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize slider to work as scroll bar. Get total number of elements in list box then manipulate value of scroll bar as per your selected entry index.

```
    <Style x:Key="backgroundSliderAlpha" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid Width="30">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneBorderColor}"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrack"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneVerticalMargin}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="8,0,8,0" Width="12" Fill="#FF487257" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalFill" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="8,0,8,0" Width="12" Fill="#FF487256" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
                                <Rectangle.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 2, 6"/>
                                </Rectangle.Clip>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalCenterElement" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Height="21" Width="7" VerticalAlignment="Top" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


 <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Width="80"  Height="492" Margin="177,43,0,72" Style="{StaticResource backgroundSliderAlpha}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Patil, Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how should I apply this to listbox or longlistselector. I'm new to windows phone 8.